# How to create query for search total sales previous year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have table named Sales.OrderValues that contain of 2 column, namely orderyear and val (total sales per day).

This is the record snippet (I cant show all of record because there are 830 rows)

[image: Sales.OrderValues]

I want to show the result like this

[image: Expected result]

But, my output is different with my expected output.

[image: My output]

As you can see, the expected output of prevtotalsales in 2008 is 618085.30. But, my output is 825169.29 (which is 208083.99 + 617085.30).

Below is my query

```
SELECT
   YEAR(D1.orderdate) AS orderyear,
   SUM(D1.val) AS curtotalsales,
   (
      SELECT
         SUM(D2.val) 
      FROM
         Sales.OrderValues D2 
      WHERE
         YEAR(D1.orderdate) > YEAR(D2.orderdate)
   )
   AS prevtotalsales 
FROM
   Sales.OrderValues D1 
GROUP BY
   YEAR(D1.orderdate);
```

How to show the SUM of totalsales at the previous year without adding the next year's totalsales?

Comment: What if you are missing a year?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want an equality condition in the `WHERE` clause of the subquery. This:

```
WHERE YEAR(D1.orderdate) > YEAR(D2.orderdate)
```

Should be:

```
WHERE YEAR(D1.orderdate) = YEAR(D2.orderdate) + 1
```

But it is much simpler and more efficient to just use `lag()`:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(orderdate) AS orderyear,
    SUM(val) AS curtotalsales,
    LAG(SUM(val)) OVER(ORDER BY YEAR(orderdate))  AS prevtotalsales 
FROM Sales.OrderValues 
GROUP BY YEAR(orderdate)
ORDER BY orderyear
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first `SUM` the values per year, and then use a cumulative `SUM`:

```sql
WITH Totals AS(
    SELECT YEAR(OV.orderdate) AS OrderYear
           SUM(OV.Val) AS YearSum
    FROM Sales.OrderValues OV
    GROUP BY YEAR(OV.orderdate))
SELECT OrderYear,
       YearSum,
       SUM(YearSum) OVER (ORDER BY OrderYear ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS PreviousCumulative
FROM Totals;
```